# Transform continuous variable to discrete variable

Tags: clustering, data-transformation, binning

I am having an input data set( 14 x 250 )  which has attached a labels set ( 1 x 250 ).

The labels set is discrete( 0 vs. 1). The problem is that the each one of the 14 characteristics are continuous. For example, for characteristic 1 I am having :

```
10.18 ; 11.18 ; 9.89 ; 22.45
0     ; 1     ; 0    ; 0
```

I want to transform the continuous variables to discrete variables, and while I am doing this I want to have a Mutual Information value between the transformed characteristics and the label values, as high as possible.

Also, I want to keep the number of variables in which I split each characteristic as low as possible, because I want to use them for a Bayesian Network model.

Could you recommend me some transform algorithms/techniques for this? Or some matlab build in functions.

I know that I can apply the mean and standard deviation for each characteristic and then build the labels based on it, but I am not sure whether the mutual information value will be high.

Comment: Sounds like BART or CART (Bayes/Conditional additive regression trees)?

Comment: You did not explain why you want to discard so much of the information in the continuous variables.  Any categorizations will be arbitrary and information, precision, and power-losing.